# Proof for beginners

Tags: real-analysis, book-recommendation, formal-proofs

Hi guys I am looking for a book on proofs and how should I approach them. I have never done proofs before in my life and this is my first time. I have done basic mathematics by serge Lang that I saw in some similiar post but they all were at high level so were the book's. So if someone could recommend a book for complete beginner and then something after I have done the beginner book

Comment: I would recommend ‘How to prove it’ by Velleman. https://www.amazon.co.uk/s/?ie=UTF8&keywords=how+to+prove+it&index=aps&tag=googhydr-21&ref=pd_sl_70bk2ucb9h_e&adgrpid=55903362889&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvadid=259041619401&hvpos=&hvnetw=g&hvrand=14803760754169935957&hvqmt=e&hvdev=t&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=1006893&hvtargid=kwd-297355531418&hydadcr=24401_1816044&gclid=EAIaIQobChMIkZDLh6_86QIVy-vtCh2gyQW9EAAYASAAEgJlFPD_BwE

Comment: Here are a couple of possibilities: I haven't read them myself but ratings on Amazon are good: https://www.amazon.co.uk/How-Prove-Daniel-J-Velleman/dp/1108439535/  https://www.amazon.co.uk/How-Think-Like-Mathematician-Undergraduate/dp/052171978X/

Comment: I just want to know what you mean by "complete beginner." Are you literally starting proofs for the first time in, say, Algebra 1? Or are you talking about more complex proofs?

Comment: @FruDe  yes I am literally starting proofs I mentioned I have done basic mathematics by serge Lang and it did have proofs which I tried but I am looking for a book that soley focuses on teaching proofs and helps you build a mathematical intuition for them

Answer (score 1):

The book *Theorems, Corollaries, Lemmas, and Methods of Proof* by Richard J. Rossi can be useful. For example, how to prove that a sequence converges? A detailed explanation is given on [pages 168-170](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=kSwVGbBtel8C&pg=PA168&lpg=PA168&dq=%22Algorithm+for+Proving+a+Sequence+Converges%22&source=bl&ots=z52a8N-axM&sig=ACfU3U1UCI4mLwRTjGEtIW9Xa2Mk-udvIA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjl8eSFsPzpAhX5JrkGHYP8CfAQ6AEwAHoECAEQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22Algorithm%20for%20Proving%20a%20Sequence%20Converges%22&f=false).

From the preface:

> Specifically, this book has been written to prepare students for rigorous mathematical reasoning of junior/senior-level courses on advanced calculus, real analysis, and modern algebra.

Comment: This seems great from just the title so I will surely Check it out and see if it helps. Thank you for suggestion and time

Answer (score 0):

You can try *How to prove it* by Velleman as @Jamminermit said in the comments (I've just downloaded the book, it seems a nice book) or you can try going directly to some beginner books in abstract algebra or even real analysis, depending on your interest. This could be challenging sometimes, if you don't have enough practice, but maybe you could grasp at least 70%-80% of the material.

If you want to learn how to prove a statement in mathematics, in my opinion the best method is learning by doing with subjects of your interest. However if you just want to have an overview of the subject, the book I mentioned seems a good one.